# How to get the remote IP in a ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have this class and wants to log the rest-requests:

```
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        LOG.info("REST-Request from '{}' for '{}'", "XXX", requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
        // ... and do some auth stuff (not relevant for this question)
    }
}
```

How do do I get the remote IP of the request? TIA!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestFilter.class);

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    // rest of your stuff here
```

Comment: How would I do this if I let Guice do my injection?

Comment: What version of Jersey 2.0 does this work?  `2.25.1` does not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

A late reply, but this may help others using Grizzly2 ...

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Request;

public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestFilter.class);

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

    @Inject
    private Provider<Request> grizzlyRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String remoteIpAddress;
        if (httpServletRequest != null) {
            // JSR-315/JSR-339 compliant server
            remoteIpAddress = httpServletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
        } else {
            // Grizzly2 server
            remoteIpAddress = grizzlyRequest.get().getRemoteAddr();
        }
```

Comment: What version of Jersey 2.0 does this work?  `2.25.1` does not work for me.

Comment: I was using Jersey 2.19 and Grizzly 2.3.22.